# What are the most common non-BMP Unicode characters in actual use?

Tags: unicode, cjk, codepoint, surrogate-pairs, astral-plane

In your experience which Unicode characters, codepoints, ranges outside the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane) are the most common so far? These are the ones which require 4 bytes in UTF-8 or surrogates in UTF-16.

I would've expected the answer to be Chinese and Japanese characters used in names but not included in the most widespread CJK multibyte character sets, but on the project I do most work on, the English Wiktionary, we have found that the [Gothic alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gothic_alphabet) is far more common so far.

**UPDATE**

I've written a couple of software tools to scan entire Wikipedias for non-BMP characters and found to my surprise that even in the Japanese Wikipedia Gothic alphabet is the most common. This is also true in the Chinese Wikipedia but it also had many Chinese characters being used up to 50 or 70 times, including "", "", and "".

Comment: @hippietrail: The main problem is that the answer will depend on the type of texts you work with. If you work on an archeological project, cataloguing texts in [Linear B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_B), you will see different non-BMP characters than when, say, working on a modern Japanese dictionary. So without narrowing down at least the type of texts, this is definitely too broad.

Comment: Personally, I don't think this question is too broad, and I would like to keep it open.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Emoji are now the most common non-BMP characters by far. , otherwise known as U+1F602 FACE WITH TEARS OF JOY, is the most common one on Twitter's public stream. It occurs more frequently than the tilde!

Comment: It is indeed the most common non BMP emoji used on twitter according to http://www.emojitracker.com/

Comment: I've been looking at statistics of text usage on the Web from the Common Crawl, by the way, and found that emoji are also the most common non-BMP characters on the Web now. They're not as common as on Twitter, of course.  is still the most common one.

Comment: @Quuxplusone Source: http://www.emojistats.org

Answer (score 74):

Excellent question!

The answer is the mathematical letters.  This past December I did a scan of the entire PubMed Open Access corpus, and came up with these figures for astral characters in it.

The first number in the figures below is how many copies of each given code point I found in the entire corpus.  First, though, to give you a notion on the relative frequencies, here are the top ten trans-ASCII code points in that corpus:

```
 2663710 U+002013 ‹–›  GC=Pd    EN DASH
 1065594 U+0000A0 ‹ ›  GC=Zs    NO-BREAK SPACE
 1009762 U+0000B1 ‹±›  GC=Sm    PLUS-MINUS SIGN
  784139 U+002212 ‹−›  GC=Sm    MINUS SIGN
  602377 U+002003 ‹ ›  GC=Zs    EM SPACE
  528576 U+0003BC ‹μ›  GC=Ll    GREEK SMALL LETTER MU
  519669 U+0003B2 ‹β›  GC=Ll    GREEK SMALL LETTER BETA
  512312 U+0003B1 ‹α›  GC=Ll    GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA
  491842 U+00200A ‹ ›  GC=Zs    HAIR SPACE
  462505 U+0000B0 ‹°›  GC=So    DEGREE SIGN
```

And here now are the trans-BMP code points, in order of decending frequency:

```
     544 U+01D49E ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL C
     450 U+01D4AF ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL T
     385 U+01D4AE ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL S
     292 U+01D49F ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL D
     285 U+01D4B3 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL X
     262 U+01D4A9 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL N
     258 U+01D4AB ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL P
     254 U+01D4A2 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL G
     185 U+01D49C ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL A
     178 U+01D53C ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL E
     137 U+01D4AA ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL O
      56 U+01D4A5 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL J
      48 U+01D4A6 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL K
      44 U+01D4B1 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL V
      43 U+01D4B2 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL W
      42 U+01D4B4 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL Y
      41 U+01D4B5 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL Z
      35 U+01D4B0 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL U
      30 U+01D4AC ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT CAPITAL Q
      23 U+01D54A ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL S
      21 U+01D539 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL B
      19 U+01D5A7 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF CAPITAL H
      18 U+01D517 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR CAPITAL T
      15 U+01D4C3 ‹›  GC=Ll    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL N
      14 U+01D535 ‹›  GC=Ll    MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR SMALL X
      13 U+01D4BF ‹›  GC=Ll    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL J
      11 U+01D540 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL I
       9 U+01D465 ‹›  GC=Ll    MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL X
       9 U+01D4CE ‹›  GC=Ll    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL Y
       9 U+01D538 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL A
       8 U+01D4C2 ‹›  GC=Ll    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL M
       8 U+01D54D ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL V
       7 U+01D4B6 ‹›  GC=Ll    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL A
       7 U+01D4BE ‹›  GC=Ll    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL I
       7 U+01D4CC ‹›  GC=Ll    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL W
       7 U+01D516 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR CAPITAL S
       7 U+01D4BE ‹›  GC=Ll    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL I
       7 U+01D4CC ‹›  GC=Ll    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL W
       7 U+01D516 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR CAPITAL S
       4 U+01D4CF ‹›  GC=Ll    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL Z
       4 U+01D53B ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL D
       4 U+01D54B ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL T
       3 U+01D4BB ‹›  GC=Ll    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL F
       3 U+01D4CA ‹›  GC=Ll    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL U
       3 U+01D507 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR CAPITAL D
       3 U+01D542 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL K
       3 U+01D546 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL O
       2 U+01D4BD ‹›  GC=Ll    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL H
       2 U+01D4C5 ‹›  GC=Ll    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL P
       2 U+01D505 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR CAPITAL B
       2 U+01D50E ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL FRAKTUR CAPITAL K
       2 U+01D541 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL J
       2 U+01D543 ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL L
       2 U+100002 ‹›  GC=Co    <private use character>
       1 U+01D4B8 ‹›  GC=Ll    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL C
       1 U+01D4C1 ‹›  GC=Ll    MATHEMATICAL SCRIPT SMALL L
       1 U+01D53D ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL F
       1 U+01D53E ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL G
       1 U+01D54C ‹›  GC=Lu    MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK CAPITAL U
       1 U+01D6A4 ‹›  GC=Ll    MATHEMATICAL ITALIC SMALL DOTLESS I
       1 U+01D7D9 ‹›  GC=Nd    MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK DIGIT ONE
```

I *really* wish I knew what they were using U+100002 to do. :(

If those aren't showing up in your browser, you should install [George Douros’s Symbola font](http://users.teilar.gr/%7Eg1951d/) or [another mirror for dowload](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/symbola). It also has all the fun Unicode 6.0.0 code points in it, too.

Answer (score 9):

For me, the [Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_Alphanumeric_Symbols) that are used for math typesetting with OpenType fonts such as Cambria Math.