# If 'ℤ' is in the BMP, why isn't it encoded in 2 bytes?

Tags: java, unicode

My question arises from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14151214/1953590), which says:

> Since 'ℤ' (0x2124) is in the basic multilingual plane it is represented by a single code unit.

If that's correct, then why is `"ℤ".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length == 3` and `"ℤ".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16).length == 4`?

Comment: For UTF-8 you might want to [read a little more about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Three bytes is the correct number. Why did you expect anything else? What *did* you expect?

Comment: That's the difference between Unicode and UTF-8. 0x2124 is only the 'sequence number' in the Unicode table. How it's encoded, often in UTF-8, takes up three bytes.

Comment: actually what is happening is that when calling getBytes it takes the string format and calculate the ascii amount of chars...internal strlen calling from c lib.

so 3bytes = 7*3=~ 21 ascii bits
which means = 21/8 = 2.625bytes
so 4bytes = 7*4=~ 28 ascii bits
28/8 = 3.5bytes
and thats why it shows, 3bytes and 4bytes because it is actually celling the length because of format size differences. ^.^ cool hey! lol

Comment: `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16)` generates BOM(byte order mark)   0xFEFF.  So the length is 4. `"ℤ".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE)` is 2 bytes.

Comment: Looking at the answers, I'd say this question has very little to do with Java, maybe remove the tag?

Comment: @saka1029: same with `StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you're mixing up two things: the character set (Unicode) and their encoding (UTF-8 or UTF-16).

0x2124 is only the 'sequence number' in the Unicode table. Unicode is nothing more than a bunch of 'sequence numbers' mapped to certain characters. Such a sequence number is called a *code point*, and it's often written down as a hexadecimal number.

How that certain number is encoded, might take up more bytes than the raw code point would.

---

**Short calculation of UTF-8 encoding of given character:**
To know which bytes belong to the same character, UTF-8 uses a system where the first byte starts with a certain amount (lets call it *N*) of `1` bits followed by a `0` bit. *N* is the number of bytes the character takes up. The remaining bytes (*N – 1*) start with bits `10`.

Hex 0x2124 = binary 100001 00100100

According to abovementioned rules, this converts to the following UTF-8 encoding:

```
11100010 10000100 10100100    <-- Our UTF-8 encoded result
^   ^ ^  ^ ^      ^ ^
AaaaBbDd CcDddddd CcDddddd    <-- Some notes, explained below
```

- `A` is a set of ones followed by a zero, which denote the number of bytes belonging to this character (three `1`s = three bytes).
- `B` is padding, because otherwise the total number of bits is not divisible by 8.
- `C` is the concatenation bits (each subsequent byte starting with `10`).
- `D` is the actual bits of our code point.

So indeed, the character ℤ takes up three bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Not all characters in the BMP are encoded using two bytes in UTF-8. Characters from `U+4016` are encoded using 3 bytes, and from `U+38E2E` using 4 bytes.

The full table can be found in the Wikipedia article on UTF-8:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8