# how get length of UTF-8 strings without mb-strlen?

Tags: php

I want to get the length of UTF-8 strings in PHP code but i havn't access to cPanel host for enable [multibyte String functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) in PHP.
is there any other way?

Meanwhile, I can not use strlen() function, because i get wrong length in UTF-8 strings.

Comment: [this](https://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/12/13/php-utf-8-string-length/) might help

Comment: Out of curiosity: why **exactly** don't you want to enable whatever PHP provides?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/symfony/polyfill-mbstring helps?

Comment: @NicoHaase I don't  access because i use shared hosting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, then you have to write it yourself.

#### UTF-8

In short, UTF-8 is encoded as follows:

- If the leftmost bit of a certain byte is a 0, then it is a single-byte character.
- If the leftmost bit of a certain byte is a 1, then it is part of a multibyte character.

  - If the 1 is followed by another number of 1s, then the number of bytes the character occupies is equal to the number of 1-bits, followed by a 0-bit.
  - Otherwise, the remaining parts of the multibyte character all start with the bits `10`.

[See here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40124195/507738).

For example, suppose we have the following string:

```
Hëllo현World
```

```
01001000 ═ H   --> Starts with 0, so it's a single-byte character
11000011 ╦ ë   --> Starts with two 1s followed by 0. Char takes up 2 bytes.
         ║         This byte is the first one of the 2 bytes. The remaining 1
         ║         byte MUST start with 10.
10101011 ╝     --> This is a 'continuation' byte, and MUST start with 10.
                   Well, it does, so it's valid.
01101100 ═ l   --> This byte start with 0, so it's a normal byte, again.
01101100 ═ l
01101111 ═ o
11101101 ╗     --> Starts with three 1-bits. So the character takes up 3 bytes.
         ║         The next 3-1=2 bytes must start with 10
10011000 ╬ 현  --> Continuation byte
10000100 ╝     --> Continuation byte
01010111 ═ W   --> Normal byte
01101111 ═ o
01110010 ═ r
01101100 ═ l
01100100 ═ d
```

#### Code

It is sufficient to just count all bytes *not* starting with bits `10`. With other words, if the byte is *not* in the range 128-191 inclusive.

```php
$str = "Hëllo현World";

// ë takes up 2 bytes
// 현 takes up 3 bytes
// In a decent browser you see 11 characters (ten Latin, one Chinese)

$len = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
    $ascii = ord($str[$i]);
    if ($ascii < 128 || $ascii >= 192) {
        $len++;
    }
}

echo "Number of bytes: ".strlen($str)."\n";
echo "Number of characters: ".$len;
```

[Here is an online demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/16a9e52fdcd28fa5ccdefb26a2070cf010002697).

---

PS: Is there a reason you don't want to enable multibyte strings?