# Escaping non-latin characters in Java

Tags: java, unicode

I have a Java program that takes in a string and escapes it so that it can be safely passed to a program in bash. The strategy is basically to escape any of the special characters mentioned [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html#Double-Quotes) and wrap the result in double quotes.

The algorithm is pretty simple -- just loop over the input string and use `input.charAt(i)` to check whether the current character needs to be escaped.

This strategy works quite well for characters that aren't represented by [surrogate pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150530/java-charat-used-with-characters-that-have-two-code-units), but I have some concerns if non-latin characters or something like an emoji is embedded in the string. In that case, if we assumed that an emoji was the first character in my input string, `input.charAt(0)` would give me the first code unit while `input.charAt(1)` would return the second code unit. My concern is that some of these code units might be interpreted as one of the special characters that need to be escaped. If that happened, I'd try to escape one of the code units which would irrevocably garble the input.

Is such a thing possible? Or is it safe to use `input.charAt(i)` for something like this?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode):

> The Java 2 platform uses the UTF-16 representation in char arrays and
>   in the String and StringBuffer classes. In this representation,
>   supplementary characters are represented as a pair of char values, the
>   first from the high-surrogates range, (\uD800-\uDBFF), the second from
>   the low-surrogates range (\uDC00-\uDFFF).

From the [UTF-16 Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+D800_to_U+DFFF):

> U+D800 to U+DFFF: The Unicode standard permanently reserves these code point values for
>   UTF-16 encoding of the high and low surrogates, and they will never be
>   assigned a character, so there should be no reason to encode them. The
>   official Unicode standard says that no UTF forms, including UTF-16,
>   can encode these code points.

From the [charAt javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)):

> Returns the char value at the specified index. An index ranges from 0
>   to length() - 1. The first char value of the sequence is at index 0,
>   the next at index 1, and so on, as for array indexing.
>
> If the char value specified by the index is a surrogate, the surrogate
>   value is returned.

There is no overlap between the surrogate pair code point range and the range where my special characters ($,`,\ etc) exist as they're all using the ASCII character mappings (i.e. they're all mapped between 0 and 255).

Therefore, if I scan through a string that contains, say, an emoji (which definitely is outside of the supplementary character range) I won't mistake either of the items in the surrogate pair for a special character. Here's a simple test program:
[image]
[image]