# regex for nested parenthesis in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm coding a calculator in Javascript.

I want to translate : `[expression1]^[expression2]` into : `Math.pow([expression1], [expression2])`

When I have simple expressions like `5^-3` it's quite easy to do with a regex, but when it comes with more complex expressions like :

`(-5*(6+3)-5)^((2*2)-2)+(4*5)`

I don't see how to deal with it with regex because of the nested parenthesis...

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: it would be also possible to have something like `(2^3)^(4^5)` ?

Comment: Regex does become very difficult to manage once you start trying to deal with nestable elements. For things like this, a parser is usually a better solution. A quick google brought up this one: http://jsfromhell.com/classes/math-parser (but I haven't tried it, and others may exist)

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan : Yep, and it becomes even harder

Comment: @SDC: Thank you, I'm gonna check on this side

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4414453/1548853

Answer (score 3):

Use regex pattern:

```
/((?:(?=[^()]*\d)\d*(?:\.\d*)?)|(?:\((?:(?:[^()]+)|(?:[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)+)\)))\^((?:(?=[^()]*\d)\-?\d*(?:\.\d*)?)|(?:\((?:(?:[^()]+)|(?:[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)+)\)))/
```

#### Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cymA2/).

---

***Explanation:***

[Step 1] :: Regex patter contains two almost same sub-patterns linked with `^` sign between

```
((?:(?=[^()]*\d)\d*(?:\.\d*)?)|(?:\((?:(?:[^()]+)|(?:[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)+)\)))
\^
((?:(?=[^()]*\d)\-?\d*(?:\.\d*)?)|(?:\((?:(?:[^()]+)|(?:[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)+)\)))
```

*The only difference is that second one (behind `^`) allows negative number as a simple parameter (`\-?`)*

[Step 2] :: Sub-pattern from *Step 1* has two alternatives:

```
(?:(?=[^()]*\d)\-?\d*(?:\.\d*)?)
|
(?:\((?:(?:[^()]+)|(?:[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)+)\))
```

[Step 3] :: First alternative is a number - for example: `1234` or `12.34` or `1234.` or `.1234`

```
(?=[^()]*\d)
\-?\d*
(?:\.\d*)?
```

[Step 4] :: Second alternative is a nested parenthesis formula

```
\(
(?:(?:[^()]+)|(?:[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)+)
\)
```

[Step 5] :: which might be simple or complex (with other parenthesis inside)

```
(?:[^()]+)
|
(?:[^()]*\([^()]*\)[^()]*)+
```

[Step 6] :: and if is complex and have some other parenthesis inside, we ensure there are nested

```
[^()]*
\(
[^()]*
\)
[^()]*
```

Comment: Thank you ! But it won't work if there are more than two nested parenthesis. I think I shouldn't use regex for this problem but parser like SDC suggested.

Answer (score 2):

browser javascript, as it is now. does not support recursive regular expressions.

my solution for this was to match a prefix with regular expressions. then to search for its parenthesis using a tokenizer approach.
then if the parenthesis are balanced then return the chunk that is inside the parenthesis.

```
// replace_tokenizer_paranthesis by shimon doodkin
// this function is searching for a regexp prefix
// then searching for a chunk inside balanced parantheseis
//
// s="s( s(gdfgs)fasd)" - searched string
// prefix=/s\(/   - searched regex for prefix
// onmatch: - replace callback function, arguments:
//  a= prefix,
//  b= inside data,
//  c = closing paranthesis
//  to return same , return  [a,b+c]
//
// example:
// replace_tokenizer_paranthesis(s,prefix,function (a,b,c){ return [ "CONVERT(",b+",DATE)"  ] }) // return [ newprefix , all rest ]

function replace_tokenizer_paranthesis(s,prefix,onmatch) 
{
 var m,start=0;
 var input;
 while(m=(input=s.substr(start)).match(prefix))
 {
    var offset_at_end=m.index+m[0].length;


    var counter = 1;

    var skip_until="";
    var i = offset_at_end;
    for(; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        //var pc = i-1>=0?input[i-1]:"";
        var c = input[i];
        if( counter===0 )
        {
            break;
        }

        //else if(c===skip_until&& pc!=='\\') //maybe backslash queoted
        else if(c===skip_until)
        {
            skip_until='';
        }
        else if(c==='"')
        {
            skip_until='"';
        }
        else if(c==="'")
        {
            skip_until="'";
        }

        else if(c==='(')
        {
            counter++;
        }
        else if(c===')')
        {
            counter--;
        }
    }
    if( counter===0 )
    {
            var result=onmatch(m[0], input.substring(offset_at_end,i-1),")")
            s=s.substring(0,start+m.index)+result[0]+result[1]+s.substr(start+i);
            start+=result[0].length;
    }
    else
      start+=offset_at_end;
 }
 return s
}
```