# JS Regex on Curly Braces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an example statement:

```
"function(){var x=0;if(true){var y=0;}}"
```

I have tried many expressions but they only return the `"{var y=0;}"`

I want to extract the following result:

```
["{var x=0;if(true){var y=0;}}","{var y=0;}"]
```

What is the best possible regex for this?

I only use JavaScript so lookbehinds are not possible.

Comment: Not possible with JS regex. Write a parser if you must.

Comment: @DavidThomas: You can do that for `{{{}}}` structure, but utterly fail with `{{}{}}`

Comment: @DavidThomas: Bracket balancing is not the only thing. Bracket can appear inside comment or string also.

Comment: Definitely have a look at a parser, e.g. http://esprima.org/.

Comment: @nhahtdh: fair point, suggestion withdrawn. =)

Comment: @FelixKling: Post your comment as an answer. I think your suggestion can be the answer to my question. So that I can check it. I am very thankful for this suggestion.

Comment: Check [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4414339/).

Comment: Also, did you try `/\{.*\}/g`?

Comment: @inhan: Check my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the following with a JS Regex tester and it seems to work:

- Pattern - `({.*((?={).*(?:})).*})`
- Test String - "function(){var x=0;if(true){var y=0;}}"
- Regex Tool - http://www.regextester.com/index2.html

This Regex works only on 2 nested curly brackets, may not work with 3 or more but the Regex can be adjusted accordingly.

Kind regards,

Yaron Shahrabani.