# Java regexp To javascript regex problems

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I have a problem with a javascript regexp.
This is my regex:

```
(([\+\-\/\*\^]?)([(]*(([(]?((([+-]?\d+([.,]?(\d+)?)?)|(Q[0-9]+)?)([e][+-]\d+)?)[)]?)|([(]?value[)]?))[)]*)?(([(]*([(]?((([+-]?\d+([.,]?(\d+)?)?)|(Q[0-9]+)?)([e][+-]\d+)?)[)]?)|([(]?value[)]?)[)]*))?([\+\-\/\*\^])([(]*(([(]?((([+-]?\d+([.,]?(\d+)?)?)|(Q[0-9]+)?)([e][+-]\d+)?)[)]?)|([(]?value[)]?))[)]*))+
```

This regexp test if the text is an matematical formula `(18*19)/2` for example, and I can add `QXX` like a variable, for example:
`Q18/42+7*Q7`

This regexp work perfectly in java (I have tested it on http://fiddle.re/dnbh6). But, when I tried to convert it in javascript, it doesnt work...
This is all solutions that I tried:

```
var reg =/(([\+\-\/\*\^]?)([(]*(([(]?((([+-]?\d+([.,]?(\d+)?)?)|(Q[0-9]+)?)([e][+-]\d+)?)[)]?)|([(]?value[)]?))[)]*)?(([(]*([(]?((([+-]?\d+([.,]?(\d+)?)?)|(Q[0-9]+)?)([e][+-]\d+)?)[)]?)|([(]?value[)]?)[)]*))?([\+\-\/\*\^])([(]*(([(]?((([+-]?\d+([.,]?(\d+)?)?)|(Q[0-9]+)?)([e][+-]\d+)?)[)]?)|([(]?value[)]?))[)]*))+/g;
reg.test("Q18+aaaa)//return true, but in java this is resturn false

var reg= new RegExp("(([\+\-\/\*\^]?)([(]*(([(]?((([+-]?\d+([.,]?(\d+)?)?)|(Q[0-9]+)?)([e][+-]\d+)?)[)]?)|([(]?value[)]?))[)]*)?(([(]*([(]?((([+-]?\d+([.,]?(\d+)?)?)|(Q[0-9]+)?)([e][+-]\d+)?)[)]?)|([(]?value[)]?)[)]*))?([\+\-\/\*\^])([(]*(([(]?((([+-]?\d+([.,]?(\d+)?)?)|(Q[0-9]+)?)([e][+-]\d+)?)[)]?)|([(]?value[)]?))[)]*))+", "g");
reg.test("Q18+aaaa)//return true, but in java this is resturn false
```

So, if you had any idea, i will try it.

Comment: http://regexpal.com/ is a nice tool to test regex expressions

Comment: keep in mind that `[(]?...[)]?` does not guarantee that all parenthesis are paired, you can open without closing and vice-versa, you need a PCRE's `(?R)` equivalent, [related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414339/recursive-matching-with-regular-expressions-in-javascript)

Comment: I hope that you generated the regex, rather than it being one long string in your program... I analyze it half way and give up, but it seems that you are using too many capturing groups.

Comment: To add to what hack.augusto said, neither Java nor JavaScript support recursive regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if that is correct what you are doing here, but I assume I know, what your problem is.

In Java if you are using the `matches()` method, it matches the regex against the complete string.

Javascript isn't doing that, it returns also partial matches. To achieve the same behaviour you have to add anchors around your regex. `^` to match the start of the string and `$` to match the end of the string.

So it should look something like this (shortened the giant regex!):

```
var reg= new RegExp("^(([\+\-\/\*\^]?)...([(]?value[)]?))[)]*))+$", "g");
  Added anchors ==>  ^                                          ^
```

Comment: This solution work perfectly with my regexp! I just need to provide the parentheses work in pairs.

Answer (score 0):

From the number of parenthesis that you have on this regex, I'm assuming you don't want to capture any data. A better regex to just validate the input might look like:

```perl
/
   [(](?R)[)] # match parenthesis
   |(?R)[-+/*^](?R) # allow to use one operator over to operands
   # a number, can be separated by "," or "." and can be followed by a exponent,
   # do _not_ accept decimal mark
   |[+-]?\d+([,.]\d+)?(e[+-]\d+)?
   |Q[0-9]+(e[+-]\d+)?
   |value
/x
```

Because of the recursion you can't use anchors, also, I used PCRE's `(?R)` you will need some sort of library support to do recursion, as said in the comments.

Edit: If you want to save the data you can write a parsing function, something with the following outline:

```js
function parse(input) {
    var output = [],
        brackets = 0,
        op = null,
        qvariable = false,
        buff = [],
        stringbuff = '',
        sign = null;

    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        var currentChar = input.charAt(i);

        if (sign && /[0-9]/.test(currentChar)) {
            return 'erro, expecting number';
        }

        if (op != null && /[-+/*(]/.test(currentChar)) {
            op = null;
        }

        switch (currentChar) {
            case '(':
                buff.push(output);
                output = [];
                break;

            case ')':
                if (op != null) { return 'operator before parenthesis close'; }
                output.push(stringbuff);
                parenthesis = output
                output = buff.pop();
                output.push(parenthesis);

                stringbuff = '';
                break;

            case '-':
            case '+':
            case '/':
            case '*':
                if (op == null) {
                    op = currentChar;
                } else {
                    if (currentChar == '-' && currentChar == '+') {
                        sign = currentChar;
                    } else {
                        return 'error, two operators in sequence';
                    }
                }
                output.push(stringbuff);
                output.push(op);
                stringbuff = '';
                break;

            case 'Q':
                if (!stringbuff.length) { return null; }
                qvariable = true;
                stringbuff += currentChar;

            // todo: handle comma, dot and exponents
            default:
                if (/[0-9]/.test(currentChar)) {
                    if (sign) { 
                        stringbuff += sign;
                        sign = null;
                    }
                    stringbuff += currentChar;
                } else {
                    return 'unexpected input';
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    if (stringbuff.length) {
        output.push(stringbuff);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: XRegExp support recursive matching, but not in the form `(?R)` like in PCRE, but you have to call a function to do it.

Comment: When I try your solution, the debug mode send me : unable to create RegExp object.