# What is wrong with these regexes with backreferences?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make a regex that will match a number of `x`'s that is a power of two.  I am using JavaScript.  I tried this one:

```
^(x\1?)$
```

but it doesn't work.  Shouldn't the `\1` refer to the outer parathesis so it should match `xx`, and therefore also `xxxx`, etc.?

I tried a simpler one that I thought would match x and xx:

```
^((x)|(\2{2}))$
```

but this only matches `x`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think a backreference can refer to the captured group of which it itself is a part.

Comment: so you want it to be able to match x, xx, xxxx, xxxxxxxx (8,16,32) etc??

Comment: Yes, that is what I want.

Comment: I think powers of two would be matched by `^((x)|(\1{2}))$` should it work properly :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do "recursive backreferences". At least, it is not so easy.

I'm no sure that you need recuresive regular expressions here. May be you could just count number of the characters in the string and check if it is equal to a power of two?

But if you really need recursive regular expressions (I'm almost sure, you don't),
you can check this question:

- [Recursive matching with regular expressions in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414339/recursive-matching-with-regular-expressions-in-javascript)

and this blog

- http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-match-nested

Comment: Can I count the number of characters using regular expression?

Comment: Also, how about my second, simpler regex.  Do you know what is wrong with that?

Comment: The second regex is wrong because you make alternatives in it and you have the ()-part in one alternative and the backreference in the other. That will not work. You can use backreferences if they matched.

Comment: Can I refer to that backreference at all from there?

Comment: @Joe: Sure. But only to that that are matched

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand.  Could you explain, maybe with an example of how to do it?

Comment: @Joe: For example, this will work `(a|(b)\2)` and this `((a)|b\2)` will not, because `(a)` belongs to another alternative, therefore will not be matched.