# Regex to match JSON in a document

Tags: regex, json

I need to find all JSON strings in a document.

- I am OK with an assumption that all strings that start with `{` are JSON.
- I am OK with an assumption that the JSON can be invalid.

Answer (score 2):

This is a regular expression solution:

```
{
    (?>
        "(?>\\.|[^"])*"|
        [^{}"]+|
        (?R)
    )*
}
```

This will capture a JSON structure that can have infinite nesting, e.g.

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "foo": false,
    "foo": 123,
    {
        "foo": "bar"
    },
    "foo": "}}}"
}
```

I have setup a [regex101 playground](http://regex101.com/r/sF0pB5/6) if you have a test case of your own or need an explanation of the expression.

Unfortunately, JavaScript [does not provide the PCRE recursive parameter `(?R)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4414453/368691). [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) is an open source JavaScript library that provides augmented regular experssions, including support for recursive matching.