# How do I write a regular expression that matches everything except a left and right parenthesis and anything between them

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using javascript and I'm trying to write a regular expression that matches anything except left and right parenthesis and anything between them.   After doing a little research, I came up with a similar example here on Stackoverflow.  In this particular example the following regular expression was used to match any three digit except 999.

```
[(?!999)(\d{3})][1]
```

This regular expression work as intended and matches 555 or 444 or 333 but not 999.

I want my regular expression to match as follow:

```
John Smith                     =>  John Smith
John Smith (RET)               =>  John Smith
Mr. John Smith's (RET) (1st)   =>  Mr. John Smith's
John William Smith (RET)       =>  John William Smith
John                           =>  John
```

This is what I have so far, but it's not working:

```
(?!\([A-Za-z]?\))(.*)
```

Can someone tell me where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
[^\(\)]*
```

I've added an illustration with an input which turns green with valid matches and red with invalid matches

```css
input:focus:invalid {
 background:red;
}
input:focus:valid {
 background:green;
}
```

```html
<input  class="pattern" pattern = "[^\(\)]*" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not sure I fully understand it.  I tried /[^\(\)]*/ on regex 101 and found that it doesn't have any capturing groups do doesn't return anything even though it has matches and 2 that it matches things in between the ( ).

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor FWIW, you need to wrap that whole regex in `()` to get capture groups, and use the global modifier, though it's probably moot since it matches everything inside the parens.

Comment: @RyanJ I tried here on regex101 (https://regex101.com/r/xM8wU8/1) as you can see, its not yielding the results I was seeking.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor yes, that's why I said FWIW (for what it's worth) and that it was probably moot (means it won't make a difference). It was for your information only.

Answer (score 2):

A more-obvious (to me, anyway) method would be to use the String.replace method with the Regex:

```
"John Smith (RET) (1st) SomethingElse".replace(/\([^\)]*\)/g, '');
```

This does not cover nested parentheses, however, in case that is at issue.  In that case, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4414453/239394) suggests using [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) to add the recursive parameter found in Perl-compatible regular expressions.

Comment: thanks for the response. I hadn't thought of using replace. I will certainly see if this works with my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
[^)](?![^(]*\))
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wZ0iA3/1