# JavaScript regex match pattern

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have to write a regex which matches the following strings:

```
Q$:ADD A GOOD QUESTION
A$:ANSWER
C$:choice0, choice1, choice2, choice2

Q$:ADD A GOOD QUESTION
A$:ANSWER
C$:choice0, choice1, choice2, choice3
```

Here, one match of regex should have `Q$:` and `A$:` and `C$:` is optional. It can be in any order. It can have any characters. And it can be in any order, `Q$:, C$:, A$: or Q$: A$: C$:`.

But it should not be `Q$: Q$: C$: A$: A$: C$:`.

I found that we [cannot use a recursive pattern in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414339/recursive-matching-with-regular-expressions-in-javascript).

I have tried, but I am not able to do with regex. I am able to do it with *string operations*, but it is lengthy.

Any idea?

I am trying to write a regex, something like `Q$:any number of words and A$: any number of words C$: this is optional, but if it is present it should have three commas and four words. And repeat this pattern.

Valid strings

```
Q$:question
A$:answer
C$:c,c1,c2,c3

Q$: question goes here
A$: Answer goes here
C$: choices, goes , here, ch
```

But there should not be any space between `Q $ :`.

And I assume the orders

```
  Q$: question goes here
  A$: Answer goes here
  C$: choices, goes , here, ch

  Q$: question goes here
  C$: choices, goes , here, ch
  A$: Answer goes here
```

should also be valid. Question must come first and choice/answer goes.

And

```
 Q$: question goes here
 A$: Answer goes here
```

This also valid string. Other valid strings are

```
 Q$: question goes hereA$: Answer goes here

 Q$: question goes here      A$: Answer goes here
```

And even choice also can come in the first line. And Can be space limited.

**Now** I don't expect regex way alone. Is there another way to do it efficiently? I mean reusable and easily changeable.

From @Wiktor's answer, I have come up with the following regex. But not up to the level I have expected.

```
     (?:Q\$:.*[\S]*[\r\n]*A\$:.*[\r\n]*C\$:.*,.*,.*,.*)|(?:Q\$:.*[\S]*[\r\n]*A\$:.*[\r\n]*)
```

Comment: Is requirement to match only capitol letter followed by `$` character ?

Comment: @guest271314 No. Only `Q$: C$: A$:` in this sensitive. Others can be small/capital letter

Comment: Is "Q\$:" part of actual input string ?

Comment: `Q$:` is the pattern to identify question and `A$:` is the pattern to identify answer and `C$:` is the pattern to identify choices. Choices are optional. If it is present it should have four choices comma separated and answer and question part is mandatory. If content has 10 questions, and one of those doesn't have valid choice it is invalid string.

Comment: _"If it is present it should have four choices comma separated and answer and question part is mandatory. If content has 10 questions, and one of those doesn't have valid choice it is invalid string."_ This description does not appear at Question. Question is only `RegExp` portion ?

Comment: It seems you can use [`/^(Q\$:.*)[\r\n]+(A\$:.*)(?:[\r\n]+(C\$:[^,\n]+(?:,[^,\n]+){3}))?/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/qT6mV8/2), or something similar. Maybe something like https://jsfiddle.net/01xeatxy/.

Comment: If you need to first *validate* the string, you need a different regex to test the input. With something like [`^(?:Q\$:.*[\r\n]+A\$:.*[\r\n]*){10}`](https://regex101.com/r/qT6mV8/3).

Comment: Does it mean a question can follow an answer? Then, my approach won't work. It requires a set order of questions and answers and choices. As for the *skipping invalid and pick only valid* - maybe [`https://regex101.com/r/qT6mV8/6`](https://regex101.com/r/qT6mV8/6) can help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please see my edit

Comment: You have no capturing groups from @WiktorStribiżew comment. But I improve that line to show the capturing groups: https://regex101.com/r/nK4aS6/1 You can see the different patterns in the matches section. You can extract that matches with javascript and split the choices and you'll get the desired result

Comment: @pranav-c-balan can you post your answer you posted earlier?