# Get text between braces {text}

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text like

```
It's a beatiful {day|morning|{month|year}} and I {watch {a serie| a movie}|play games}
```

I want to get

```
day|morning|{month|year}
```

and

```
watch {a serie| a movie}|play games
```

from this text.

Currently I have a regex using `/\{(.+?)\}/g` but it's not working when there are brackets inside brackets. This is an example from what I currently have: https://www.regextester.com/?fam=105404

As you can see, `{day|morning|{month|year}}` is not selecting completely because there are nested braces. How can I fix this?

Comment: Regular expressions are not a good tool for dealing with nested strings like this. You need to write a parser than counts left braces and doesn't complete the match until the count of right braces matches.

Comment: Check out this question. Seems like `exec` is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417/how-do-i-retrieve-all-matches-for-a-regular-expression-in-javascript

Comment: I fully agree with Barmar. In your particular example you can get the desired result by modifying the regex to `/\{(.+?)\}+/g`, and then cutting off the first and last character in each match. This will, however, *only* work in *special cases*, where the closing `}` are directly behind each other.

Comment: Also duplicate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414339/recursive-matching-with-regular-expressions-in-javascript

Comment: @EugeneTsakh What does `exec` have to do with the nested braces?

Comment: Okay, but It doesn't fix the nested braces if I use exec, right?

Comment: "/\{(.+?)\}+/g" is working and have the braces in front and after is not a problem! Thanks!