# Regular Expression: Array Match

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression to match the following array of numbers, which can be nested. These should pass:

```
[]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, [1,2,3], 5]
```

but the following should fail the test:

```
abc 
1
[1,2,3
[#]
```

This works:

```
/(^\[)(\d+\,|\s(?:(|\,))|\d+|\s\[|\]\,)*(\]$)/g
```

Is there are a better way to achieve the same result. I tried lookahead but don't fully understand it and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, [1,2,3]` also passes, I'd bet this isn't desirable?

Comment: No, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: What about `[[[1]]]`? Can there be more than one level of nesting?

Comment: See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/QIEFzf/1) for a `PCRE` engine.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, your solution is brilliant. I'm basically trying to do what JSON.parse does so you've given me a great a starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regex approach can be the following: remove brackets from all nested structures, and then check if the resulted string follows the `[`+number+1 or more repetition of `,` + numbers+`]` pattern:

```js
var s = ['[]', '[1, 2, 3]', '[1, 2, 3, [1,2,3], 5]', '1', '[1,2,3', '[#]'];
var rx = /(?!^)\[([^\][]*)]/;
var valid_rx = /^\[(?:\s*\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*)?\s*]$/;
for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
  var test_string = s[i];
  console.log(test_string);
  while (rx.test(test_string)) {
    test_string = test_string.replace(rx, "$1")
  }
  console.log(valid_rx.test(test_string));
}
```

The first regex, `/(?!^)\[([^\][]*)]/`, finds `[...]` substrings that are not at the string start position. Between `[` and `]`, there can't be `[` nor `]`. The `while` loop removes these brackets one by one until no match.

The second regex, `^\[(?:\s*\d+(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*)?\s*]$`, validates the resulting string:

- `^` - start of string
- `\[` -   a `[`
- `(?:` - a non-capturing group:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?:\s*,\s*\d+)*`  - 0 or more repetitions of `,` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces, 1+ digits
- `)?` - the end of the optional group
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `]` - a `]`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: This is a correct approach that handles any recursion level and validates any `[...]` string with only comma-separated digit chunks inside them.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer, given the regex requirement. I just want to add that `JSON.parse` can also be a solution, particularly if further processing is required on the detected array.

Comment: To be fair, the requirement was to have a regex that matches said strings. This answer uses a regex, but does not provide such regex. The real answer should be that it's not possible with JS' regex engine because it does not support recursion.

Comment: @ndnenkov That would be a comment, not an answer. At least, that would have no added value to SO. Everyone knows that [JS regex does not support recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414339/recursive-matching-with-regular-expressions-in-javascript).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew obviously either OP doesn't know or she doesn't know that it's needed to create such a regex.