# How to find all instances of a pattern with regex or regexp in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, xregexp

I have this string

```
{ prop1: 'val1', prop2:{ prop3: 'val3' ,  messages: {something:'val'}  messages: { something:'val2', x : {x : 1, y : 5} } } , prop4: 'val4' }
```

how can I find all instances of `messages: { ... }` in javascript with xregexp (or another solution)

This `/messages: (\{(?>[^{}]+|(?1))*\})/g` is working in php, but not in javascript

[image]

Also couldn't figure it out by using `xregexp` recursion http://xregexp.com/api/#matchRecursive

Tried https://repl.it/@RezaRahmati/xregexp

```
XRegExp.matchRecursive(str, 'messages: {', '}', 'gi')
```

but getting `Unbalanced delimiter found in string` error

### Update

as @vs97 and @barmar comment, I tried `messages: (\{.+\})` and works on multiline, still issue when it's single line

[image]

Comment: *maybe as simple as this?* messages: (\{.+\}) https://regex101.com/r/Fs4SAq/1

Comment: Are the messages on different lines as in regex101.com, or a single line as in the question?

Comment: [Javascript doesn't natively support recursive regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4414453/8237835) but you might be able to use a [library that does](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xregexp). Otherwise, I'd say you should make/use a simple parser as this JSON-like structure doesn't look like a regular language. Especially if your format doesn't rely on white space to separate the lines and only the `{}` are important.

Comment: @Khauri The question says he tried to use that library.

Comment: I can't read. But in that case I think it'd be nice to see the code for what OP tried.

Comment: @vs97 thanks, although it works in regex101 but in my code result is not correct
`        str = str.replace(/messages: (\{.+\})/gm, 'x');
        console.log(str);` and result is `{ prop1: 'val1', prop2:{ prop3: 'val3' ,  x` which last `}` is missing

Comment: @Barmar right now on multiple lines

Comment: `.+` shouldn't match across line breaks.

Comment: That test has the messages object on the same line as the last `}`, which is why it's removing it. But if they're on lines by themselves the suggested regexp should work.

Comment: @Barmar yes it works on multiline, what about single line?

Comment: It won't work on a single line, you need to match balanced braces, that's why I asked if the actual string is multiline.

Comment: @Barmar so what do you suggest as solution for single line?

Comment: @Barmar my string is more complicated than this (I simplified for SO question)

Comment: Show what you tried using `xregexp`. It should be able to do it.

Comment: @Barmar it's in the question

Comment: @Barmar please see this https://repl.it/@RezaRahmati/xregexp

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `matchBalanced()` is not useful for this, because of this:

> An error is thrown if delimiters are unbalanced within the data.

So you can't use it just to find the balanced parts of the string, you can only use it with data that's expected to be balanced -- it returns the outermost substrings. Since what you're looking for are the balanced parts that are nested inside, it won't return them.

Comment: thanks for answer, it explains why my regexp is not working, but still my problem is not solved

Comment: See the last line of my answer, it says how you can combine this with other code to solve the problem.

Comment: how to find every instance of `messages: ` using regex?

Comment: Simple: `/messages:/g`

Comment: Sorry, I am just confused, that will find `messages: ` then how do I know how far in the string is for that `messages:` and if I found that why do I need to do that match recusrive, would you please add some psudo code about the solution?

Comment: You can just search the rest of the string for the first balanced object. Then look for the next `messages:` and do it again.

Comment: Oh I see, let me try and will get back to you if I couldn't figure it out

Comment: the solution doesn't work, when I pass rest of string to matchRecursive I get unbalanced token error. see https://repl.it/@RezaRahmati/xregexp

Comment: Apparently `matchRecursive` doesn't just return the balanced substrings, it requires all the delimiters to be balanced in the entire string. So it's not useful for this.

Comment: Is there any other solutions you can think of?

Comment: Not with JavaScript regular expressions. You need something that implements PCRE so you can use recursion.