# JS Regex for Parsing SGF (Meta)data

Tags: javascript, regex, ecma, regex-recursion

SGF is what's widely used to save Go (board game) games as text. One example of how it saves its data is this — as a whole, SGF is a text-based representation of a *trie*, which means it is recursive, but this question is regarding only the data in each node —:

```
GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2023-12-25]
```

Data is saved as pairs of strings plus data within brackets (`[]`). The keys are usually of length 2, but not necessarily so; moves are encoded as `B[aa]` or `W[bb]`, where `B` denotes Black, and `W` is White, while `aa` and `bb` are the coordinates on the board.

My question is: what would then be the regex to extract these data groups as key-value objects? (I'm using JavaScript or TypeScript here.)

---

### References

- [SGF Documentation](https://www.red-bean.com/sgf/)
- [SGF Alternative Documentation](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Eaeb/go/misc/sgf.html)
- [Sabaki's SGF Parser](https://github.com/SabakiHQ/sgf)
- [My own SGF parsing project](https://github.com/psygo/sgf-parser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. If only trying to match the (meta)data

Assuming only the simplest rules, the regex that you (might be) looking for is:

```js
/(?<key>[A-Z]+)\[(?<value>(?:\\\]|[^\]])*)\]/gy
```

...where the `g` flag stands for "[global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global)" (matches all instances) and `y` for "[sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky)" (each match either starts at the very first character or right after the end of the last match). If you are 120% confident that the content is valid, feel free to drop the `y`.

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const properties = /(?<key>[A-Z]+)\[(?<value>(?:\\\]|[^\]])*)\]/g;

const testcases = [
  '(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2023-12-25];B[pd];W[dd];B[pq];W[dp])',
  '(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2023-12-25];B[pd];W[dd](;B[pq];W[dp])(;B[dp];W[pp]))',
  '(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2023-12-25];B[pd];W[dd](;B[pq];W[dp])(;B[dp];W[pp];PL[B]AE[jk]AB[jj]AW[ji];B[jq]))',
  '(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2023-12-25];B[pd]C[Comment on move.];W[dd](;B[pq];W[dp])(;B[dp];W[pp];PL[B]AE[jk]AB[jj]AW[ji]C[Comment on editing.];B[jq]))'
];

for (const testcase of testcases) {
  console.log(
    [...testcase.matchAll(properties)].map(
      ({ groups: { key, value } }) => ({ key, value })
    )
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

### 2. On the Full Grammar

According to [the second link](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Eaeb/go/misc/sgf.html), this is the full SGF grammar:

```
Collection     = { GameTree }
GameTree       = "(" RootNode NodeSequence { Tail } ")"
Tail           = "(" NodeSequence { Tail } ")"
NodeSequence   = { Node }
RootNode       = Node
Node           = ";" { Property }
Property       = PropIdent PropValue { PropValue }
PropIdent      = UcLetter { UcLetter }
PropValue      = "[" Value "]"
UcLetter       = "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" | "E" | "F" | "G" | "H" | "I" |
                 "J" | "K" | "L" | "M" | "N" | "O" | "P" | "Q" | "R" |
                 "S" | "T" | "U" | "V" | "W" | "X" | "Y" | "Z"
```

Rule *Tail* is recursive, which means it is impossible to rewrite a rule depending on it (*Collection*, *GameTree* and itself) as an [ECMAScript-compliant](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-patterns) regex.

PCRE, on the other hand, has support for recursive pattern:

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<Collection>
    (?:(?&GameTree)(?:\s*(?&GameTree))*)?
  )
  (?<GameTree>
    \(\s*
    (?&RootNode)\s*
    (?&NodeSequence)\s*
    (?:(?&Tail)(?:\s*(?&Tail))*)?\s*
    \)
  )
  (?<Tail>
    \(\s*
    (?&NodeSequence)\s*
    (?:(?&Tail)(?:\s*(?&Tail))*)?\s*
    \)
  )
  (?<NodeSequence>
    (?:(?&Node)(?:\s*(?&Node))*)?
  )
  (?<RootNode> (?&Node) )
  (?<Node> ;\s*(?:(?&Property)(?:\s*(?&Property))*)? )
  (?<Property>
    (?&PropIdent)\s*
    (?&PropValue)(?:\s*(?&PropValue))*
  )
  (?<PropIdent> [A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])* )
  (?<PropValue> \[ (?&Value) \])
  (?<Value> (?:\\\]|[^\]])* )
)
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/BnOrFA/2).

---

Assuming *Tail* cannot contain itself (i.e. `Tail = "(" NodeSequence ")"`), the *GameTree* rule can be rewritten as (~1100 characters):

```js
/\(\s*;(?:[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\](?:\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\])*(?:\s*[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\](?:\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\])*)*)?\s*(?:;(?:[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\](?:\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\])*(?:\s*[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\](?:\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\])*)*)?(?:\s*;(?:[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\](?:\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\])*(?:\s*[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\](?:\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\])*)*)?)*)?\s*(?:\((?:;(?:[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\](?:\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\])*(?:\s*[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\](?:\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\])*)*)?(?:\s*;(?:[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\](?:\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\])*(?:\s*[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\](?:\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\])*)*)?)*)?\)(?:\((?:;(?:[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\](?:\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\])*(?:\s*[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\](?:\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\])*)*)?(?:\s*;(?:[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\](?:\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\])*(?:\s*[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\](?:\s*\[(?:\\\]|[^\]])*\])*)*)?)*)?\))*)?\s*\)/
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/6eU22m/1).

This only ever validates the content, giving you no groups. However, even if groups were added (e.g. `\(\s*(?<rootNode>...)(?<nodeSequence>...)(?<tails>...)\s*\)`), they would have to be re-parsed using the other rules.

That said, assuming non-recursive structure, a parser using pure regex would repeat itself a lot.

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.
>
> — Jamie Zawinski ([Coding Horror blog post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/))

Code used to generate the monster above:

```js
const rules = (() => {
  const value = String.raw`(?:\\\]|[^\]])*`;
  const propIdent = String.raw`[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*`;
  const propValue = String.raw`\[${value}\]`;
  const property = String.raw`
    ${propIdent}\s*
    ${propValue}(?:\s*${propValue})*
  `;
  
  const node = String.raw`;(?:${property}(?:\s*${property})*)?`;
  const rootNode = node;
  const nodeSequence = String.raw`(?:${node}(?:\s*${node})*)?`;
  const tail = String.raw`\(${nodeSequence}\)`;
  
  const gameTree = String.raw`
    \(\s*
    ${rootNode}\s*
    ${nodeSequence}\s*
    (?:${tail}(?:${tail})*)?\s*
    \)
  `;
  const collection = String.raw`(?:${gameTree}(?:\s*${gameTree})*)?`;
  
  const rules = {
    collection, gameTree,
    tail, nodeSequence, rootNode, node,
    property, propIdent, propValue, value
  };

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(rules)) {
    rules[key] = new RegExp(value.replace(/\s+/g, ''));
  }
  
  return rules;
})();
```

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const rules = (() => {
  const value = String.raw`(?:\\\]|[^\]])*`;
  const propIdent = String.raw`[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*`;
  const propValue = String.raw`\[${value}\]`;
  const property = String.raw`
    ${propIdent}\s*
    ${propValue}(?:\s*${propValue})*
  `;
  
  const node = String.raw`;(?:${property}(?:\s*${property})*)?`;
  const rootNode = node;
  const nodeSequence = String.raw`(?:${node}(?:\s*${node})*)?`;
  const tail = String.raw`\(${nodeSequence}\)`;
  
  const gameTree = String.raw`
    \(\s*
    ${rootNode}\s*
    ${nodeSequence}\s*
    (?:${tail}(?:${tail})*)?\s*
    \)
  `;
  const collection = String.raw`(?:${gameTree}(?:\s*${gameTree})*)?`;
  
  const rules = {
    collection, gameTree,
    tail, nodeSequence, rootNode, node,
    property, propIdent, propValue, value
  };

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(rules)) {
    rules[key] = new RegExp(value.replace(/\s+/g, ''));
  }
  
  return rules;
})();

console.log(rules);

const testcases = [
  '(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2023-12-25];B[pd];W[dd];B[pq];W[dp])',
  '(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2023-12-25];B[pd];W[dd](;B[pq];W[dp])(;B[dp];W[pp]))',
  '(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2023-12-25];B[pd];W[dd](;B[pq];W[dp])(;B[dp];W[pp];PL[B]AE[jk]AB[jj]AW[ji];B[jq]))',
  '(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2023-12-25];B[pd]C[Comment on move.];W[dd](;B[pq];W[dp])(;B[dp];W[pp];PL[B]AE[jk]AB[jj]AW[ji]C[Comment on editing.];B[jq]))'
];

for (const testcase of testcases) {
  console.log(testcase.match(rules.gameTree));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, as a whole, SGF is basically a text representation of a *trie*, I believe. But this question is specifically regarding the data in each node, that's what the snippet I provided in the question is about, which is way simpler.

Comment: I think it is possible to use recursive regexes in JS, but it needs an external package such as [XRegExp](https://xregexp.com/), which is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4414453/4756173).

Comment: Thank for the recursive answer regex though. I think I'm also going to create a question about it in the near future, and tag you so you can get the points right away :)

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro By "ECMAScript-compliant", I mean an instance of the built-in `RegExp` class. That plugin for sure doesn't just rely on the native implementation, so it doesn't count. Also, thanks for the invitation :)

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro Answer updated, by the way.

Comment: Nice, thanks! But what was expected in that snippet? The printed arrays seem to be only a copy of the SGF string?

Comment: In your answer, the regex I was looking for is apparently this: `/[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*(?:\\\]|[^\]])*]/g`. And with this, I can extract the `<key>[<value>]` pattern through this: `const regex = /[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*(?:\\\]|[^\]])*]/g; const matches = [...metadataAndMoves[0].matchAll(regex)];`. But how do I  get capture groups for the key and the value?

Comment: Ok, this `/(?<key>[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*)(?<value>(?:\\\]|[^\]])*)/g` is the regex with the capturing groups. Now the last thing is to skip `[` in the `value` group.

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro As I said, "*this only ever validates the content*". Assuming only the simplest rules, use [`(?<key>[A-Z]+)\[(?<value>(?:\\\]|[^\]])*)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/6eU22m/3). It's basically your regex, with a `\[` added before `(?<value>...)`.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're referring to as "only validates the content". Are you referring to the fact that that rule is only one tiny part of the puzzle and that I would have to recurse things in order to parse the SGF? If so, this question is actually *only* supposed to be about that specific rule, not the recursion part. That regex does seem to work. And in my case I also don't need to anything to validate the string, I'm considering it was properly constructed SGF string. If you add that regex plus the tiny JS regex matching I mentioned (to the top), I'll accept the answer.

Comment: At any rate, thank you very much for the very complete answer!

Comment: @PhilippeFanaro Added. I originally thought this was meant to be a generic question regarding the gory details of the grammar so my answer was written as such.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77718740/4756173)'s that question I had promised. I think you've probably already done most of the work already. I intend on giving that question a bounty at some point, since it's way more work than usual.