# Recursive Regex for Parsing SGF with JS

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, ecma, regex-recursion

### 1. What SGF is

SGF is what's widely used to save Go (board game) games as text. In essence, it's basically the text encoding of something like a *tree*.

Here's an example of what it looks like — I suggest using software like the [Sabaki editor](https://sabaki.yichuanshen.de/) to create files and then look at the resulting text in it —:

```
(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2023-12-25];B[pd];W[dd](;B[pq];W[dp])(;B[dp];W[pp]))
```

A more readable version, only for reference — the comments are not part of the SGF specification actually —:

```
(
  ;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2023-12-25] // Game Metadata
  ;B[pd] // Black's Move (`pd` = coordinates on the board)
  ;W[dd] // White's Move
    ( // Parentheses denote a branch in the tree
      ;B[pq]
      ;W[dp]
    )
    (
      ;B[dp]
      ;W[pp]
    )
)
```

The whole SGF grammar is described like [this](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Eaeb/go/misc/sgf.html):

```
Collection     = { GameTree }
GameTree       = "(" RootNode NodeSequence { Tail } ")"
Tail           = "(" NodeSequence { Tail } ")"
NodeSequence   = { Node }
RootNode       = Node
Node           = ";" { Property }
Property       = PropIdent PropValue { PropValue }
PropIdent      = UcLetter { UcLetter }
PropValue      = "[" Value "]"
UcLetter       = "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" | "E" | "F" | "G" | "H" | "I" |
                 "J" | "K" | "L" | "M" | "N" | "O" | "P" | "Q" | "R" |
                 "S" | "T" | "U" | "V" | "W" | "X" | "Y" | "Z"
```

### 2. What I'm Looking For

What I'm looking for is a recursive regex capable of turning an SGF string down to a recursive tree object in JS. Checking if the file is valid SGF would be a plus, but not necessary.

The tree shape would be something like this — this one comes from [Sabaki's SGF Parser](https://github.com/SabakiHQ/sgf?tab=readme-ov-file#node-object) —:

```js
{
  id: <Primitive>,
  data: {
    [property]: <Array<String>>
  },
  parentId: <Primitive> | null,
  children: <Array<NodeObject>>
}
```

ECMA, the standard for JS, doesn't comprise recursive regexes. So, an external package would probably necessary, like the [XRegExp](https://xregexp.com/) package, mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4414453/4756173).

### 3. An Attempt with XRegExp

From XRegExp's docs, we have the [`matchRecursive`](https://xregexp.com/api/index.html#matchRecursive) function, which seems to be exactly what I needed. But it is somehow not doing anything?

```
const testSgf = "(;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2023-12-25];B[pd];W[dd](;B[pq];W[dp])(;B[dp];W[pp]))"

const matchRecursive = 
  XRegExp.matchRecursive(testSgf, "\\(", "\\)", "g")
// Returns the SGF itself? Why?
// Shouldn't it break it down from the `(` and `)` nesting delimiters?
```

### 4. My Non-Regex Solution (Optional)

Others have, in the past, parsed SGF through various means, I'll leave my own version here for reference, as it might help in understanding the problem — you can also find it [here on Github](https://github.com/psygo/sgf-parser). It uses a tree class and some sort of flattened recursion:

```
export class SgfTree {
  constructor(
    // The pointer to the parent isn't really necessary, but
    // it makes parsing much easier.
    public parent?: SgfTree,
    public data: string = "",
    public children: SgfTree[] = []
  ) {}

  toJSON(): Object {
    return {
      data: this.data,
      children: this.children.map((c) => c.toJSON()),
    };
  }
}

// An SGF tree is basically a *tree* data structure encoded
// in text.
//
// I bet you could also do the whole parsing with only
// Regexes. (I think I'm gonna create a Stack Overflow
// question for this.)
export function parseSgf(sgf: string) {
  // 1. Cleanup
  sgf = sgf
    .replaceAll("\n", "")
    .replaceAll("\t", "")
    .replaceAll(" ", "")
    .trim();

  // 2. Initialization
  const trees = new SgfTree();
  let currentTree: SgfTree = trees;
  let currentString: string = "";

  // 3. Flattened Recursion
  for (const char of sgf) {
    switch (char) {
      case "(":
        // 3.1. Opening a Branch
        currentTree.data = currentString;
        const newTree = new SgfTree(currentTree);
        currentTree.children.push(newTree);
        currentTree = newTree;
        currentString = "";
        break;
      case ")":
        // 3.2. Closing the Current Branch and Going Back to the
        //      Parent.
        parseMovesAndMetadata(currentString);
        currentTree.data = currentString;
        currentTree = currentTree.parent!;
        currentString = currentTree.data;
        break;
      default:
        currentString += char;
    }
  }

  return trees.children;
}

// Not all the SGF fields, but probably the most common ones...
export type SgfData = {
  // 1. Metadata
  GM?: "1"; // Game Type (GM = "1" is Go)
  FF?: string; // File Format
  CA?: string; // Character Set
  AP?: string; // Application used to produce the file
  // 2. Game Info
  KM?: string; // Komi
  SZ?: string; // Board Size
  DT?: string; // Date
  HA?: string; // Number of Handicap Stones
  RU?: string; // Rules Set in Use
  GN?: string; // Game Name
  EV?: string; // Event
  // 3. Players
  PB?: string; // Black Player
  BR?: string; // Black's Rating
  PW?: string; // White Player
  WR?: string; // White's Rating
  // 4. Comments
  C?: string; // (Move) Comments
  GC?: string; // Game Comment
  // 5. Editing the Goban
  PL?: string; // Who plays next
  AB?: string; // Add Black stones
  AW?: string; // Add White stones
  // 6. Moves
  B?: string; // What Black plays
  W?: string; // What White Plays
};

// TODO: Complete
function parseMovesAndMetadata(sgfData: string) {
  const metadataAndMoves = sgfData
    .split(";")
    .filter((m) => m !== "");

  const regex =
    /(?<key>[A-Z](?:\s*[A-Z])*)\[(?<value>(?:\\\]|[^\]])*)/g;
  const matches = [...metadataAndMoves[0].matchAll(regex)];

  console.log(matches[0].groups!["value"]);
}

// Straight Branch
const test1 = `
  (
    ;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2023-12-25]
    ;B[pd]
    ;W[dd]
    ;B[pq]
    ;W[dp]
  )
`;
// Two Branches
const test2 = `
  (
    ;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2023-12-25]
    ;B[pd]
    ;W[dd]
      (
        ;B[pq]
        ;W[dp]
      )
      (
        ;B[dp]
        ;W[pp]
      )
  )
`;
// Two Branches + Added (Edited) Stones
const test3 = `
  (
    ;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2023-12-25]
    ;B[pd]
    ;W[dd]
      (
        ;B[pq]
        ;W[dp]
      )
      (
        ;B[dp]
        ;W[pp]
        ;PL[B]AE[jk]AB[jj]AW[ji]
        ;B[jq]
      )
  )
`;
// Two Branches + Added (Edited) Stones + Comments
const test4 = `
  (
    ;GM[1]FF[4]CA[UTF-8]AP[Sabaki:0.52.2]KM[6.5]SZ[19]DT[2023-12-25]
    ;B[pd]C[Comment on move.]
    ;W[dd]
      (
        ;B[pq]
        ;W[dp]
      )
      (
        ;B[dp]
        ;W[pp]
        ;PL[B]AE[jk]AB[jj]AW[ji]C[Comment on editing.]
        ;B[jq]
      )
  )
`;

const sgf = parseSgf(test4);
const sgfAsJSON = sgf.map((c) => c.toJSON());
const prettyPrintSgf = JSON.stringify(sgfAsJSON, null, 2);

// console.log(prettyPrintSgf);
```

### 5. References

- [XRegExp - `matchRecursive`](https://xregexp.com/api/index.html#matchRecursive)
- SGF

  - [SGF Documentation](https://www.red-bean.com/sgf/)
  - [SGF Alternative Documentation](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Eaeb/go/misc/sgf.html)
- Sabaki

  - [Sabaki Editor](https://sabaki.yichuanshen.de/)
  - [Sabaki's SGF Parser](https://github.com/SabakiHQ/sgf)
- Others

  - [Stack Overflow - JS Regex for Parsing SGF (Meta)data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77717462/4756173)
  - [My own SGF parsing project](https://github.com/psygo/sgf-parser)

Comment: JavaScript regex does not support recursion at the time of writing. Also, regexes don't make trees, so you'll anyhow need JS code to do the job.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I suggested using a non-native package for the recursive regex, such as [XRegExp](https://xregexp.com/). And I didn't say I wanted something to strictly *only* use regexes.

Comment: does it have to be a regex? That format can be trivially parsed with peg.js or similar, a hand-coded top-down shouldn't be hard either.

Comment: That's nice to know, thank you very much. I didn't know there was a package for parsing *any* grammar. I think that, for this question specifically though, I'll leave it to using only a recursive regex, sorry.

Comment: Ok, I've added one of my feeble, initial attempts with XRegExp.

Comment: If the non-regex solution isn’t relevant why is it included? Why use a regex to parse when you have the grammar (and parsers)?

Comment: I only left the non-regex solution so people could see it from a more or less standard perspective. For your second perspective: I wanted to learn how to solve this problem with a recursive regex, that's all. Besides, with that kind of thinking, so many unorthodox things would have never been created ever...

Comment: How is your expected answer to this question different from the answer you got to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77717462/js-regex-for-parsing-sgf-metadata)?

Comment: That answer uses PCRE's recursive regex, and a recursive function in JS without recursive regex. I don't think PCRE is available on JS, not natively, I believe. But now that I think about it maybe I could use some sort of port like [@desertnet/pcre](https://github.com/desertnet/pcre)'s?

Comment: @Nick - They said they'd post a similar Q with a bounty for the person who tried to answer the last Q to answer. Little shady, but seen worse on here.

Comment: @l3l_aze what I don't get is why not just put a bounty on that question...

Comment: If you guys read that question and the comments, you will see that that question was about only the metadata inside each move basically, not the recursive part of the grammar.

Comment: "What I'm Looking For: ..." no it isn't. This is a classic case of [the XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), what you want is _anything_ that gets you a tree representation of an SGF file. You don't care whether that's regex or not. You want the result. So look for that: there are [a lot](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:sgf) of javascript SGF parsers on npm: do none of those work for your use-case? Because "what you're looking for" is by your own admission, literally sabaki's parser output. So just.. use that?

Comment: That's definitely not true, because then I would have been content with *my own solution* in section 4, or Sabaki's. I'm really looking for how to do this with a recursive regex solution. I totally understand people not wanting to answer this question, feel free not to. But I just don't get why looking for **an alternative solution** to a solved problem is such a heresy or foreign concept to people commenting here. Alternative algorithms for problems are a thing in software and in life.

Comment: Just curious. Why are you focused on JavaScript? With the advent of WebAssembly, you could code this in C# and use all the recursion you want.

Comment: @ax. - I wonder if your trie->tree edit might be incorrect. I'm not really a DSA person, but [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)s are a thing.

Comment: @halfer My edit was based on the observation that at the SGF File Format site, there is [zero mention of "trie"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.red-bean.com%2Fsgf%2F+trie), but [quite some of "tree"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.red-bean.com%2Fsgf%2F+tree). Also, I [did not find any other correlation between "SGF format" and "trie"](https://www.google.com/search?q=sgf+format+trie). And lastly: which mere mortal knows what a "trie" is? :)

Comment: Heh yes @ax., good points.  I just wanted to mention it in case you happened to see that a trie might fit the context. I'm happy to leave it be.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `XRegExp` and the answer will start very incomplete and is not tested. It thus needs completion from either the OP himself or somebody else.

According to the [API documentation](https://xregexp.com/api/index.html#matchRecursive) of `XRegExp.matchRecursive`

> Returns an array of match strings between **outermost** left and right delimiters.

this function doesn't seem to look automatically for nested matches (one can see this even in the first example on the documentation page). So one has to do that oneself. The result of applying `matchRecursive(testSgf, "\\(", "\\)", "g")` to `testSgf` will return an array with one entry (namely `testSgf` itself -- this is also what is observed in the third section of the question -- but with the difference that the outermost brackets should already be removed in this entry). Applying `matchRecursive` again to this single entry should return an array with now two entries. So `matchRecursive` has to be applied recursively to the array entries of its result until the result is an empty array.

This is only a starting point and certainly has to be extended to take into account the remaining grammar of the SGF format.

Comment: @Philippe Fanaro not interested in finding a solution anymore, or was my suggestion of no help?